# Can I animate(scale) just one component of an android layout and have the layout update during animation

Tags: android, animation

Imagine I have a toolbar implemented as a horizontal LinearLayout as follows:

```
  [___Button1____] [___Button2___] [___Button3___] [___Button4___]
```

When someone clicks on Button2, I want the toolbar to change to:

```
  [___Button1____] [___________Button2___________] [___Button3___]
```

The toolbar should transition from the first state to the second state through a smooth animation. I would like to use a scale animation on Button2, and while that is happening, Button3 and Button 4 should move to the right (while the animation is going on). At the end of the animation (or maybe during), I will fade Button4 out.

Question: How do I achieve an animation of the layout of the toolbar such that only one component (i.e. Button2) is being scaled while the others are not being scaled - the layout is simply updated during the animation of Button2.

I looked at LayoutAnimationController, but it does not appear to allow me to either:
  1. specify different animations for the different components, OR
  2. indicate that only animate one component and don't animate the others.

I can't scale the entire toolbar because that distorts Button1/3/4 which I don't want.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm trying to do something similar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the `ListView`, can you try adjusting my code?
Though I am not sure how you are handling your button events:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    iv.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Note in your case you will be working with the Button view and not the ImageView.

Regards

Comment: This technique does not work in my case. It simply animates the button, without updating the layout.